# How to implement fields and address them like chess

Tags: python, algorithm, field

I'm trying to implement a game called Pah Tum. (It's not relevant how it works for my issue.)  I want to create a field in a console like this:

```
  A  B  C  D
1 [] [] [] []
2 [] [] [] []
3 [] [] [] []
4 [] [] [] []
```

I already figured out how to print that BUT: 
I want to define a function in which I can address specific fields and block them, like this:   B3

```
  A  B  C  D
1 [] [] [] []
2 [] [] [] []
3 [] [X][] []
4 [] [] [] []
```

Somehow I can't figure out how to do that without using hundred of lines of code where I print that step by step.

Comment: Have you considered nested lists, where each list repersents a row?

Comment: Use a `2d` list and what you mean by _block a field_?

Comment: SO is not like casual email or text messaging.  Try to use capital I's and contractions  correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class and use `__setitem__`:

```
import string
class Board:
   def __init__(self, width):
      self.w = width
      self.board = [[[] for i in range(width)] for b in range(width)]
   def __setitem__(self, coords, val):
      self.board[coords[0]][coords[-1]] = [val]
   def __repr__(self):
      return ' '+'  '.join(list(string.ascii_lowercase[:self.w]))+"\n"+'\n'.join(string.ascii_lowercase[a]+' '.join(str(i) for i in b) for a, b in enumerate(self.board))

board = Board(4)
board[(2, 2)] = 'X'
print(board)
```

Output:

```
  a  b  c  d
a[] [] [] []
b[] [] [] []
c[] [] ['X'] []
d[] [] [] []
```